# After downloading an application with two Launcher components from the Marketplace, clicking "Open" will cause a crash

Tags: android, marketplace, app-launcher

Create a sample application with two launcher icons.  For example, two 
components such as:

```
<application ...> 
  <activity ... android:name="TestActivity01"> 
    <intent-filter> 
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
  </activity> 
  <activity ... android:name="TestActivity02"> 
    <intent-filter> 
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
  </activity> 
</application>
```

Either install the application via downloading from the Marketplace, or via 
AppInstaller.  When the message box asks you if you would like to run the 
application, an exception is thrown:

```
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395): 
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity 
class {com.xxx.xxx/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity}; have you 
declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1
480)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1454)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2660)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2704)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
com.android.packageinstaller.InstallAppDone.onClick(InstallAppDone.java:105
)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2344)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4133)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6504)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3672)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:882)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEv
ent(PhoneWindow.java:1712)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneW
indow.java:1202)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:1987)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(P
honeWindow.java:1696)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1658)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:
791)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
02-03 16:42:44.270: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(395):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The crash happens because `com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity` is 
trying to find a (single) component which resolves the following intent:

```
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Please note that this has been tested BOTH with the AppInstaller, and the 
actual Marketplace on a real device.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround solution from Mike worked for me:

Note that the activity-alias tag must be declared *after* the activity tag you are referring to (n the xml).

see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6579

Comment 2  by Moussa.Mike, Mar 30, 2010

For a proper workaround add this activity-alias to your manifest:

```
<activity-alias android:name="com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity"
                android:targetActivity=".Main" android:exported="true">
```

Replace `.Main` with your .ClassName that you want to launch as the default when the
Open button is hit in this one case

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine the problem is having two `android.intent.action.MAIN` activities.  Both cannot be the main `Activity` for your task — you need to decide on one.

Otherwise, if you want to have multiple launcher icons, then retaining the `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` categories is fine.

Comment: If i remove the Main, crash go away but doesn't server the purpose what i want to do. I would like to have two different Icons on application tray so that i can start different activities.

Icon only show up in tray if we define the intent with Main and Launcher.

e.g.
    <intent-filter> 
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
    </intent-filter> 

I have seen same type of filter used for DialtactsActivity(android source).

Comment: Issue 6579:
After downloading an application with two Launcher components from the
Marketplace, clicking "Open" will cause a crash
 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6579

Comment: No, read the Contacts source again. They use an `<activity-alias>`, so only **one** actual `Activity` is the `MAIN` one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that. I did try that, but i still see the crash.
So i was not sure whether ALIAS is necessary to achieve what i want to do. I want to add more things, looks like space is very limited for adding comments.

Comment: <activity  android:name="TestActivity01"> 
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</activity> 
<activity  android:name="TestActivity02"> 
</activity> 
<activity-alias android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:name="TestActivity03"
android:targetActivity="TestActivity02"
android:icon="@drawable/Test2"
>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
  </activity-alias>

Comment: You can edit your original question to provide updates. Your problem there is that you still have two distinct Activities with a `MAIN` action.

Comment: Thanks. If i remove the MAIN, i don't see the two icons on the application tray. FYI..if i load the application using ADB everything works. So it proves something is broken when we start the application from the market place/app installer.
But this is the way how DialtactsContactsEntryActivity defined.
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#acttask

An activity is set up as the entry point for a task by giving it an intent filter with "android.intent.action.MAIN" as the specified action and "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" as the specified category. (There's an example of this type of filter in the earlier Intent Filters section.) A filter of this kind causes an icon and label for the activity to be displayed in the application launcher, giving users a way both to launch the task and to return to it at any time after it has been launched.